# How To Execute Login Items Before Application Reopen?

Tags: restart

System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> [user] -> Login Items

seem to be executing after, or at least in parallel with, the application reopens on reboot.  In my case this is undesirable because I have software that must run in order to keep the system from crashing when applications like Chrome start running.

I know I can turn off application reopen but that's not what I want either.

How can I specify that I want the Login Items to open first?

Failing that, how can I specify that I want one of the Login Items to open first?

Comment: There seems to be a larger issue if you have to “run in order to keep the system crashing when apps like Chrome start.”

Comment: Yeah, the larger issue is I don't have the money to buy a new Mac and the GPU chipset in the 2010 Macbook Pro isn't properly supported by more recent versions of the OS and Apple has been bugged about it ad infinitum and... nuff said?

Comment: What do you mean "the GPU chipset in the 2010 Macbook Pro isn't properly supported by more recent versions of the OS"?  Apple either supports your Mac model or it doesn't; there's no in between here.  I suspect this is a logic board issue and not something with macOS itself.

Comment: However, let's see what we can see... Can you provide the output of the command `ls ~/Library/LaunchAgents` and post it to your question.

Comment: An indepth description of the problem is in this post at macrumors:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/gpu-kernel-panic-in-mid-2010-whats-the-best-fix.1890097/

Comment: $ ls ~/Library/LaunchAgents
com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist   com.dropbox.DropboxMacUpdate.agent.plist
com.adobe.GC.Invoker-1.0.plist   com.lastpass.LastPassHelper.plist
com.bittorrent.uTorrent.plist   com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist

Comment: Please post it to the original question, it's super difficult to parse it as a comment.

Comment: That MacRumors post is a just a very long thread on how to avoid actually fixing the problem - which is to replace the failed GPU.